# Why does FPS go down if canvas is larger than 255x220?

Tags: firefox, html5-canvas

I've found a wierd phenomenon with HTML5 canvas. I was getting a lower than expected framerate, but only in Firefox, and only on one computer (but not on another I tested). The wierd thing is, if I reduce the canvas size to be 255x250 or less, Firefox performs similar to other browsers. If I add one more pixel in width, the FPS falls rapidly to a third.

I've made a jsPerf to demonstrate the problem: http://jsperf.com/critical-canvas-size
(Make sure that the grey rectangle is on screen. I let the tests fail if not, because I found it changes the results if you scroll away accidentally.)

All four test cases are pretty similar with most browsers on most systems, but on this one PC with Firefox 17, I see the following:

[image]

The PC in question is running an older Red Hat Linux, and I guess it probably doesn't have hardware accelleration support (from the OS side).

So, what could be the cause for this? Is there anything I can do in my code to circumvent the issue? (I've been thinking about using several small canvasses instead of one large one, for example.)

---

Edit:
Here is a standalone html file [that exibits the problem](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/web/jsfiddle/tiles_test_251.html?w=AABbwN00-D_gbHnd4yXxukqbPzumtbAf671CufK4Bw8L7A), and [one that doesn't](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/web/jsfiddle/tiles_test_250.html?w=AADveBbhaESeH49N7j3NRlHsilRA8LDX-yIYBKtPJMuMLw). The only difference is the width of the canvas, 251 vs. 250. (You can comment out the spinner animation, it is just to make the problem visible. Also please excuse the accuracy of the FPS timer, its implementation is very simple.)

The 250px version gets about 60 FPS, in fact it seems to be capped. You can increase the `numIterations` variable to make the frame function draw a multiple amount of tiles. I can get up to numIterations = 100, or 120000 tiles/sec, while still having a decent framerate. However, the 251px version gives me even for numIterations = 1 a framerate below 20, or less than 1000 tiles/sec.

Comment: I'm not sure your results are directly tied to the size of the canvas.

Comment: What else could it be? The canvas size is the only thing I'm varying. I tried many different sizes. Below 255x250 (or 300x212) it's smooth, add one pixel in width or height and the framerate drops to a third. I'm definitely drawing the same number of pixels in both cases.

Comment: Your test is assuming that `requestAnimationFrame` will always be resolved at consistent intervals, which simply isn't true. While it could be a problem with the FF build, I think the test can't exactly be relied upon. For example, I get a variance of +/- 10 fps on each of the different tests, with no apparent cause (Chrome 24, Win 7). I'd suggest running the test more, possibly changing the order the tests are run in, and then you might be able to determine some correlation.

Comment: The problem is not the jsperf! The problem occurs in a standalone HTML file, namely that the animation I'm drawing gets super jerkey. I just made the jsperf to try to demonstrate it. (Un?)fortunately the problem seems to only occur on certain systems. (By the way, the test measures the average time from the requestAnimationFrame call till the callback is finished, where I would normally issue another call. This is the actual number I'm interested in, since it limits the maximum framerate.)

Comment: Is the animation that the jsPerf uses the same animation from your problem code?

Comment: My problem code drew about 100 64x32 tiles (png or bmp, I was trying to see was was faster). I added the circle animation as a visual indicator of the frame rate, and to check that my function was ideed called regularly. However it doesn't really matter what I draw, I see the effect anyway. I could easily draw 100x the tiles on another computer with the same FPS. When I was investigating why that one particular PC was so slow, I found that it reached similar performance as the others when I made the canvas small - and not gradually, but suddenly!

Comment: I'll try doing more tests when I have access to the other computer, and the original script, tomorrow.

Comment: The tests run fine for me - only 1.5 frames difference between the fastest and slowest result.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense because drawing to the canvas and clearing the canvas are expensive methods; if you have a smaller canvas and call `clearRect` on it every animation step then it will perform better than a larger canvas running the exact same code. The best thing to do is optimise your draw method *to only clear what changed each frame*. Once you do that you will notice a performance boost; [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/) will help with other areas in which you can increase performance.

I'm developing with canvas too and have found that WebKit based browsers, in general, handle canvas operations quicker than Gecko in most cases.

Comment: It's not the clearRect, I just added two example HTML files which exibit the problem, but don't use clearRect. Both draw the exact same number of pixels.

Comment: In fact, clearRect shouldn't make a difference, since it is a) basically just a `memset` behind the scenes, b) in the jsperf I always clear 200x200 pixels, and c) even if I would draw more pixels, any operation on the 1px wider canvas should just take ~1/250=0.4% more time (not 200%).

Answer (score 0):

I actually see similar behavior.  I believe it is when you cross the 65776 pixel barrier -> not 65536 as you would expect.

I don't yet know *why* this is the case, but it is likely some kind of internal data structure or data type issue (possibly its using a hash and needs to grow the table at that point) inside your browser.  Your test is actually invalid on my chrome browser - it does not exhibit the same performance drop.

I wrote some test cases
http://jsperf.com/pixel-count-matters/2
and
http://jsperf.com/magic-canvas/2

Hope this helps!